# Pulse audio and connection refused in openbox in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, openbox

Please find the attached below screenshot of the error I am getting.

[image: Pulse audio error screenshot]

I am getting this error when I start my Ubuntu 16.04 machine in openbox session when my app play the mp3 files.

The error is something like "Pulse audio manager error, failed to connect with context and connection refused".

But when I do the same process in gnome-desktop session (instead of the openbox session) then it works fine and my app play the mp3 file without any issue.

If anybody has any idea about this issue then please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My qt app tried to play mp3 files in openbox but it gives gstreamer and pulseaudio related error.

So I decided to start my app in openbox and  when it just try to rum mp3 files then my app switches from openbox window manager to ubuntu desktop ( because as I mentioned in my question when I do the same process in gnome-desktop session (instead of the openbox session) then it works fine and my app play the mp3 file without any issue)  and it gives me the above mentioned error.

So I have started thinking in  direction of "Pulse audio manager error".  But during debug I found that the issue in switching from openbox to ubuntu desktop and it causes the above error.

So I run the below set of commands and repeat the same set of command 4-5 times in my qt program and it resolved my issue. Here 'nw' is nodejs program and lighttpd it web server.

**pkill -f lighttpd**

**pkill -f nw**

**openbox --exit**

And now my app start in openbox and before playing mp3 files it switched into ubuntu deskop and play mp3 files without any issue and error.

**NOTE : My app started lighttpd and nw. So if my app does not kill lighttpd and nw (in case of above error) then the error persists. That is why my app is killing the lighttpd and nw to resolve the error.**